# Getting data from SysListView32

Tags: vba, vb6

I am trying to get data from a `SysListView32` using `LVM_GETITEMTEXT` but I just get an empty string. It gives me the number of characters but doesn't display the actual text. Can anyone help please? Code is as follows

```
Private Const LVM_FIRST As Long = &H1000
Private Const LVM_GETITEMTEXT As Long = (LVM_FIRST + 45)

Private Type LV_ITEM
    mask         As Long
    iItem        As Long
    iSubItem     As Long
    state        As Long
    stateMask    As Long
    pszText      As String
    cchTextMax   As Long
    iImage       As Long
    lParam       As Long
    iIndent      As Long
End Type

Dim lvi As LV_ITEM
Dim r as long 

lvi.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH
lvi.pszText = Space$(MAX_PATH)

r = SendMessage(Handle, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, 0, lvi)

data = Left(lvi.pszText, r)

If Trim(data) <> "" Then MsgBox (data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You [need to set the `LVIF_TEXT` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx) to declare that `pszText` points to a valid buffer.

```
Private Const LVIF_TEXT As Long = &H1
```

```
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT
lvi.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH
lvi.pszText = Space$(MAX_PATH)
```

Comment: thanks for that but still no joy, still getting an empty string.

Comment: @Amir How is `SendMessage` declared, what is in `r`, and doesn't the listview have the [LVS_OWNERDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739(v=vs.85).aspx#LVS_OWNERDATA) style?

Comment: Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Comment: r gives me the number of characters placed in a specific row, r = SendMessage(Handle, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, i, lvi) so i here basically points to a specific index and it is working fine but I don't gt the text placed on that index. Using Spy++ it tells me class name is SysListView32 and the caption is List1

Comment: Using SendMessage(hFocus, WM_GETTEXT, lcount, ByVal sx), I can read the title of the window

Comment: @Amir Using Spy++ can you [see `LVS_OWNERDATA`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfHZG.png) in the list of styles?

Comment: No I can't its showing WS_CHILD, WS-VISIBLE, WS_HSCROLL, WS_TABSTOP, LVS_REPORT,LVS_SINGLESEL, LVS_NOSORTHEADER